# rails if else check fails then rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, before-filter, rescue

I have 2 methods in my controller for finding the user (notice the `enabled_only` scope):

```
before_filter :find_user, :only => :show
before_filter :find_any_user, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

def find_user
  @user = User.enabled_only.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  flash[:alert] = "The user you were looking for could not be found"
  redirect_to root_path
end

def find_any_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  flash[:alert] = "The user you were looking for could not be found"
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Surely these could be merged into one method that checks whether `:action == 'show'` but I couldn't get the rescue to catch the error. I tried something like the following but it didn't work:

```
before_filter :find_user, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def find_user
  @user = if :action == 'show'
    User.enabled_only.find(params[:id])
  else
    User.find(params[:id])
  end
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  flash[:alert] = "The user you were looking for could not be found"
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Please advise on how this can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the code you want to 'protect' between a `begin`and a `rescue`

```
before_filter :find_user, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def find_user
  begin
    @user = if :action == 'show'
      User.enabled_only.find(params[:id])
    else
      User.find(params[:id])
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    flash[:alert] = "The user you were looking for could not be found"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

and by the way your test `:action == 'show'` can never be true. `:action` is a symbol which value is `:action`, its value will never change, same for `'show'`, its value will never change. I'm not sure what's the best way to achieve this but you could do but you could do `if params[:action] == "show"`

Comment: You can rescue from errors within a method without `begin`/`end`. http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-rescue